# Pandas: Append list having list of dictionaries to existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe. I am grouping it by columns A, B and applying a function to each group. The function returns a list of dictionaries where each dictionary has to be appended as rows to a new dataframe. This is what I have done:

```
def foo(x):
   new_row = []
   new_row_dict = {}
   for i in items:
         new_row_dict['A'] = value1
         new_row_dict['B'] = value2
         new_row_dict['C'] = value3
         new_row_dict['D'] = value4
         new_row.append(new_row_dict)
   return new_row # Returns a list of dictionaries
   # new_row = [{'A': value1, 'B': value2, 'C':value3, 'D':value4}, {'A': value11, 'B': value22, 'C':value33, 'D':value44}]
   


df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D"])
df = df.append([foo(x) for _, x in df1.groupby(['A', 'B'])], ignore_index=True)
```

But I am getting the error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'`. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: What return `print (df1.groupby(['A', 'B']).apply(foo))` ?

Comment: We need to flatten the nested list of dictionaries. Check `df = df.append(np.hstack([foo(x) for _, x in df1.groupby(['A', 'B'])]), ignore_index=True)` OR `df.append([y for _, x in df1.groupby(['A', 'B']) for y in foo(x)], ignore_index=True)`

Comment: @ Shubham Sharma, Thank you but unfortunately it's not working though. I am getting a dataframe with NaN values.

Comment: @ jezrael, I am getting a series.

Comment: @Animeartist - How working `df1.groupby(['A', 'B']).apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(foo(x)))` ?

Comment: @jezrael, Thankyou for getting back but it isn't working though.

Comment: @Animeartist - hmm, so it means there is some complex data returned?

Comment: @jezrael, A list having dictionaries is returned. Each dictionary represents a row which is to be appended into existing dataframe,

Comment: @Animeartist - Can you add some sample dict instead `new_row` and test it for see error?

Comment: @jezrael, Please see the edits. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure test `[{'A': value1, 'B': value2, 'C':value3, 'D':value4}, {'A': value11, 'B': value22, 'C':value33, 'D':value44}]` instead `new_row` and failed?

Comment: @jezrael, The real list returned is somewhat like this: `[{'A': array(['value1'], dtype=object), 'B': array(['value2'], dtype=object), 'C': 'value3', 'D': nan}, {'A': array(['value11'], dtype=object), 'B': array(['value22'], dtype=object), 'C': 'value32', 'D': 'value44}]`

Comment: Tested your solution and no error, can you upgrade pandas?

Comment: @jezrael, I am still getting this error though: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'`. I believe the returned list should be unpacked before appending it into the dataframe though.

Comment: @jezrael, I made few changes in my code and now it's working as expected. Thank you so much!